# webview not generating completely as bitmap in lollipop android

Tags: android, webview, bitmap

I want to generate bitmap from webview full page.

some codes

Below code for generating Bitmap from webview

Webview to Bitmap :

```
 Picture p = webview.capturePicture();
    webview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);   
    webview.buildDrawingCache();
    final PictureDrawable pictureDrawable = new PictureDrawable(pict);

            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            try
            {
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(pictureDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),pictureDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
            }
            catch (OutOfMemoryError e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            canvas.drawPicture(pictureDrawable.getPicture());
            webview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

below code for to save the file in memory for that

To save as file :

```
if(bitmap!=null)
{
      File myDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "AackAack");
      if (myDir.exists()) 
      {
      }
      else 
      {
      myDir.mkdir();        
      }
      String fname = System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png";
      file1 = new File(myDir, fname);
      try 
      {
      FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file1);
      result.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 10, out);
      out.flush();
      out.close();
      } 
      catch (Exception e) 
      {
      e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
```

here webview loading fine but not generating as bitmap completely in lollipop.
this problem is getting only in lollipop devices. and same code when runs on kitkat then its working fine..

how can i resolve this issue? please help me..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call WebView.enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw() before creating any WebViews. That is, if you have any WebViews in your layout, make sure you call this method before calling setContentView() in your onCreate() shown below.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
    webview.enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw ();
}
```

and its worked fine for me..

Thanks